# Combine classes from multiple files into single namespace in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

In typescript, I want to instance a class using its name as a string. I found that this works:

```
const googlecommand = Object.create((Commands as any)['GoogleCommand'].prototype);
```

The above line is in a separate file from `GoogleCommand`. Command needs to be a namespace for this to work (some examples out there say it may be present on `window` by default but that's not the case for me) and if I simply had all my "Command" classes in a single file with namespace Command around it, that would be fine because I could have a single `import Commands from 'AllCommands'` line but that makes organizing the code a lot more difficult as I want to have a lot of commands.

So, what I want to achieve now is to have each of my commands in a separate .ts file and then have a single namespace that contains all of them.
To summarize, this is what I want to have as a concept (but won't work as it is now):

```
    // GoogleCommand.ts
    export namespace {
        export class GoogleCommand extends AbstractCommand {
            ....
        }
    }
```

```
    // BingCommand.ts
    export namespace {
        export class BingCommand extends AbstractCommand {
            ....
        }
    }
```

```
    // CommandProcessor.ts
    import { AbstractCommand } from './AbstractCommand';
    import { Commands } from './GoogleCommand';
    import { Commands } from './BingCommand';    // This will obviously conflict

    // The commandName value will come from an exteral config file so its value
    // is unknown at this point (except that it will definitely be the name of one of the commands
    let commandName;
    commandName = 'GoogleCommand';
    const googlecommand: AbstractCommand = Object.create((Commands as any)[commandName].prototype);
    commandName = 'BingCommand';
    const bingcommand: AbstractCommand = Object.create((Commands as any)[commandName].prototype);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to either rename your classes to specialise them by their name (which is what you are doing at runtime), or else alias them on import and write a map:

```
// CommandProcessor.ts
import { AbstractCommand } from './AbstractCommand';
import { Commands as GoogleCommands } from './GoogleCommand';
import { Commands as BingCommands } from './BingCommand';    

const Commands = {
   GoogleCommand: GoogleCommands,
   BingCommand: BingCommands
}

// The commandName value will come from an exteral config file so its value
    // is unknown at this point (except that it will definitely be the name of one of the commands
let commandName;
commandName = 'GoogleCommand';
const googlecommand: AbstractCommand = Object.create(Commands[commandName].prototype);
commandName = 'BingCommand';
const bingcommand: AbstractCommand = Object.create(Commands[commandName].prototype);
```

I'm not sure what the idea / benefit of using a namespace is. That was one of ideas in TypeScript that Anders says was a mistake.

I would just straight up export the class.

Comment: That won't work because I don't know what command I will need. The actual command name comes from a string with a value that is unknown at the point the code is called

Comment: Let me edit it to show a more full example, and see if it does what you want.

Comment: That works exactly as I need it to, thank you. I wasn't set on using namespaces, it was just the only working example that I could find.